# Disable status reson in campaign Form in CRM2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

How to **Disable the status reason control when the status is "Approved"** which is in campaign in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM?How to Write the Workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do this using some JavaScript in the onload event. To get the current status you would need to look up the "statecode" attribute like this:

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("statecode")
```

Note: I believe you will need to add the Status field to your form (you could probably hide the field as well) in order to access this using this method.

Next, depending on what state code is used for "Approved" you would handle accordingly. The code to disable a field is something like this:

```js
var control = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("YourAttributeName");
control.setDisabled(true);
```

Comment: @CornerGalla    without using javascript can i do that?..is possible to create workflow and use for do that process?

Comment: You cannot disable a field on a form using a workflow (if that is what you're asking). Workflows are processes that run asynchronously (and independently) of forms. You can make them fire/run if somebody *changes* the status, but you cannot make a workflow physically *interact* with a form.

Comment: (Can people be careful with edits please, you made part of the answer a little ambiguous)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the control you need to use javascript, because you want an UI binding (appearance of the field connected to his value)

You can enforce this binding by a plugin to don't update the record if your condition is not respected.